# How to extract keywords from text in Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Using the excerpts method, I have some keywords with 5 words around, but not the original text with highlighted keywords.

How can I extract tokenized keywords and highlight them in the original text?

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx allows you to specify retrieving more than five words around the matches:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts
http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/excerpts.html

But I don't think there's any way to have the entirety of the original text returned - you could set `around` to be very, very big, but Sphinx probably isn't built to handle that reliably/quickly. Perhaps it's worth looking at other tools to handle this aspect?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pat! I have content with text and pictures, and I want to give it in the search results "as is" with highlighting keywords. Is there any way to extract tokenized keywords from excerpts? I'm looking for "call keywords" function, but I can't understand how to use it with Thinking Sphinx.

Comment: `keywords` is the excerpts functionality - same thing, just different label (it was excerpts in the old binary syntax). You could try manually grepping through your content to highlight your search keywords - it's going to be more reliable than Sphinx if your content is HTML, but granted, still not ideal.